# Huge innodb tables with SELECT performance issue

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, innodb

I have two huge innodb tables (`page`: +40M rows, +30Gb and `stat`: +45M rows, +10Gb). I have a query that selects rows from the join of these two tables and it used to take about a second for execution. Recently it's taking more than 20 seconds (sometime up to few minutes) for the exact same query to be completed. I suspected that with lot's of inserts and updates it might need an optimization. I ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on the table using phpMyAdmin but no improvements. I've Googled a lot but couldn't find any content helping me on this situation.

The query I mentioned earlier looks like below:

```
SELECT `c`.`unique`, `c`.`pub`
    FROM `pages` `c`
    LEFT JOIN `stat` `s` ON `c`.`unique`=`s`.`unique`
    WHERE `s`.`isc`='1'
      AND `s`.`haa`='0'
      AND (`pubID`='24')
    ORDER BY `eid` ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

These are the tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `eid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ti` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `fat` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `de` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `fad` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `pub` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `pubID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pubn` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `unique` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `pi` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `kw` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `fak` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `te` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `fae` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
ALTER TABLE `pages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`eid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ` (`unique`(128)),
  ADD KEY `pub` (`pub`),
  ADD KEY `unique` (`unique`(128)),
  ADD KEY `pubID` (`pubID`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `faT` (`fat`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `faA` (`fad`,`fae`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `faK` (`fak`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `pubn` (`pubn`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `faTAK` (`fat`,`fad`,`fak`,`fae`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `ab` (`de`,`te`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `Ti` (`ti`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `Kw` (`kw`);
ALTER TABLE `pages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `TAK` (`ti`,`de`,`kw`,`te`);
ALTER TABLE `pages`
  MODIFY `eid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


CREATE TABLE `stat` (
  `sid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `unique` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `haa` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `isc` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
ALTER TABLE `stat`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`unique`(128)),
  ADD KEY `isc` (`isc`),
  ADD KEY `haa` (`haa`),
ALTER TABLE `stat`
  MODIFY `sid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The following query took only 0.0126 seconds with 38685601 total results as said by phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT `sid` FROM `stat` WHERE `s`.`isc`='1' AND `s`.`haa`='0'
```

and this one took 0.0005 seconds with 5159484 total results

```
SELECT `eid`, `unique`, `pubn`, `pi` FROM `pages` WHERE `pubID`='24'
```

*Am I missing something? Can anybody help?*

Comment: Help you based on what? You have not shared any specific information that would enable us to help you.

Comment: I've added the query and table structures. Hope these help.

Comment: I see unique is tinytext. Can you add an autoincrement primary key? It would help a lot for the join

Comment: At the very least I would use varchar if you can because varchar is stored with the row rather than tinytext stored separately from what I understand

Comment: @YounElan, if you look closer both tables have primary key with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  That unique column needs to be tinytext as it's length might exceed limitations not under my control. I added Unique Key with 128 char as its length inevitably

Comment: Your manner of showing the table definition is strange, and has errors. Why can't you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to show the *final* table?

Comment: @BillKarwin, that is due to confidentiality of the database that I'm working on and I'm supposed to not release any type of information about that. That's why I needed to manually change the wordings of the table structures, causing some problems and errors. Sorry for the confusion, which is out of my hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slowdown is probably due to scanning so many rows, and that is now more than can fit in cache.  So, let's try to improve the query.

- Replace `INDEX(pubID)` with `INDEX(pubID, eid)` -- This may allow both the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` to be handled by the index, thereby avoiding a sort.
- Replace `TINYTEXT` with `VARCHAR(255)` or some smaller limit.  This may speed up tmp tables.
- Don't use prefix index on `eid` -- its an `INT` !
- Don't say `UNIQUE` with prefixing -- `UNIQUE(x(128))` only checks the uniqueness of the first 128 columns !
- Once you change to `VARCHAR(255)` (or less), you can apply `UNIQUE` to the entire column.
- The biggest performance issue is filtering on two tables -- can you move the status flags into the main table?
- Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.
- What does `unique` look like?  If it is a "UUID", that could further explain the trouble.
- If that is a UUID that is 39 characters, the string can be converted to a 16-byte column for further space savings (and speedup).  Let's discuss this further if necessary.

5 million results in 0.5ms is bogus -- it was fetching from the Query cache.  Either turn off the QC or run with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE...`

Comment: very informative points. Thanks! Before seeing your answer here I did the sixth recommendation of yours, which seems to solve the problem at least for now. `eid` was not supposed be in `UNIQ` and was a typo in here. Column `unique` cannot have specified length as I have no control on its content and they can be of any length.

Comment: "Can be of _any_ length"??  `TINYTEXT` is limited to 255 bytes.

Comment: Oh! `TINYTEXT` is somehow equal to `VARCHAR(255)`, I've missed that! Does it worth converting it on these very huge tables? I may take hours for the conversion!

Comment: No, it is probably not worth a special effort.  But if you need to do a big `ALTER` for other things, include this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put that in my to-do list

Comment: Rick, I couldn't wait longer and tried to do this chance and see its effects on the performance. As I have multiple giant tables having the same issue I started one by one from smaller ones. Now that I have reached the very huge ones MySQL is not able to perform the `ALTER TABLE` function anymore and it keeps saying `MySQL has gone away`. What should I do now? Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a timeout issue.  Sorry, I can't point to exactly what to change.  It depends on which client you are using, the settings in `my.cnf`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @RickJames answer, but following it I have done a test.

I would also recommend you do not use the name `unique` for a column name, because it's an SQL reserved word.

```
ALTER TABLE pages 
  CHANGE `unique` objectId VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Document Object Identifier',
  DROP KEY pubId,
  ADD KEY bktest1 (pubId, eid, objectId, pub);

ALTER TABLE stat 
    CHANGE `unique` objectId VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Document Object Identifier',
    DROP KEY `unique`,
    ADD UNIQUE KEY bktest2 (objectId, isc, haa);

mysql> explain SELECT `c`.`objectId`, `c`.`pub`     FROM `pages` `c` JOIN `stat` `s` ON `c`.`objectId`=`s`.`objectId`     WHERE `s`.`isc`='1'       AND `s`.`haa`='0'       AND (`pubID`='24')     ORDER BY `eid` ASC LIMIT 0, 10;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys           | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ref    | unique,unique_2,bktest1 | bktest1 | 4       | const                       |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | NULL       | eq_ref | bktest2,haa,isc         | bktest2 | 388     | test.c.objectId,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

By creating the multi-column indexes, this makes them covering indexes, and you see "Using index" in the EXPLAIN report.

It's important to put `eid` second in the bktest1 index, so you avoid a filesort.

This is the best you can hope to optimize this query without denormalizing or partitioning the tables.

Next you should make sure your buffer pool is large enough to hold all the requested data.

Comment: There is a semantic change, here.  Previously, `UNIQUE` applied to one column; now it applies to 3.  Please check that this is ok.

Comment: Yes, that's true, it needs to be checked that it's okay.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks for your answer. I'm not good at multi-column indexes and don't know how they work! :(

Comment: @SAVAFA, you might like my presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really and the video too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: After reading your slides now I'm understanding your point much better. Thanks Bill

Comment: @BillKarwin, what if I have different `WHERE` condition search patterns based on users' search with different order types. Do I need to make index for every possible combination?

Comment: @SAVAFA, that's a really difficult scenario to support. I often say, "you can't optimize for *every* usage, by definition," because optimizing means to make some usages more efficient, at the cost of making other usages less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)
Does everything you've mentioned in your slides apply to FT index as well?

Comment: @SAVAFA, no, FT indexes are not used for SQL search predicates other than `MATCH()`, and they're not used for joins or sorting or covering indexes. You might like http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql